# Can't print correctly in landscape on A4 size with CSS (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I have a html table with some data and it looks much better if printed in landscape mode.

so far the css code is:

```
@page {
    size: landscape;
    max-height:100%; 
    max-width:100%;
    margin-top: 1.2cm;
    margin-bottom: 1.2cm;
    margin-left: 1cm;
    margin-right: 1cm;
    width: 276mm;
    height: 190mm;
}
```

When you print it like this, all the divs that have some bootstrap rule (col-xs-6 for example) don't get printed correctly, meaning they print with a big side margin (at least 7-8cm on both sides).

I don't understand why this happens only in landscape, if I change the css to print in portrait, it prints correctly!

And I noticed that when I'm in the print preview (chrome) and if I select A5 instead of the default A4 size paper, magically the print preview shows the tables printed correctly, but of course I can't proceed to print like this because the printer asks for A5 paper.

Any idea why is this happening?

ps.: just posted the print css code, because besides bootstrap, there is no code on the tables and the div that cointains them that could disrupt the printing.

ps2.: with dev tools on chrome, before printing, If I select the divs containing the tables and remove the 100% width given by col-xs-12, it partially fixes the layout on the print preview, so I'm pretty sure it has to do with boostrap

Comment: if I do this:

`size: A3 landscape;`

and in the printer settings I keep format as A4, it fixes everything BUT the printed tables are smaller, they dont take all the space on the landscape A4 printed page, it seems everything is about 80% size

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using? bootstrap 4 fixed some obscure bootstrap 3 printing rules, and then bootstrap 5 removed a lot of printing style too, moving from 3 to 5 fixed most of my printing issues.

Answer (score 3):

after many trials I found a working solution myself,

```
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    size: 287mm 210mm;
}
```

I honestly don't know why it works, but when I define size to 287mm instead of the default A4 width of 297mm, it magically fixes itself

Comment: But this solution is about override the rule?